# Combining CSS pseudo-classes nth-child and not

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a table and I want to shade each alternate row, apart from the row with the class "`openingTimes`".

This opening times row should not be shaded, but the pattern after this row should be continued, like this, (with bold representing shading!):

> [ **Info 1** ] [ Info 2 ] [ Opening Times Row ] [ **Info 3** ] [ Info
>   4 ] [ **Info 5** ] [ Info 6 ]

The CSS I have is:

```
table tr:not(.openingTimes):nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

But what this results in is:

> [ **Info 1** ] [ Info 2 ] [ Opening Times Row ] [ Info 3 ] [ **Info
>   4** ] [ Info 5 ] [ **Info 6** ]

I want the Info 3 to be shaded and the pattern to continue from there.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**Edit: OK, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QWjnm/**

Comment: JSfiddle...you know the drill.

Comment: Why not just add a class to each of the rows (excluding `.openingTimes`), then apply `nth-child()` to that class?

Comment: `nth-child` does not work on  siblings with different classes, at least not the way you might think it will.

Comment: OK, added http://jsfiddle.net/QWjnm/

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I could do yes, I'm more just trying to clarify the behaviour of this selector as the results surprised me :)

Comment: Actually @AustinBrunkhorst, that doesn't work either - seems like it is just ignoring the class selector completely: http://jsfiddle.net/U3fqA/

Comment: I believe @AustinBrunkhorst meant to give only those trs that you want to shade another class. Like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/U3fqA/1/). I still think mine works better though.

Comment: To re-interate `nth` selectors do **NOT** work on classes only elements.

Comment: Yeah I think @MrLister 's solution gets me what I actually want in this case, if you add it as an answer I'll accept :)

Comment: Wait a minute. Stupid question, but do you _need_ to shade the first row? Otherwise, you could just write `tr:nth-child(even)` which just happens to skip the openingTimes one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nth-child syntax isn't complex enough to allow for what you want.

In your example however, you can write

```
tr:first-child, tr:nth-child(2n+4)
```

for a selector.

This means use the first child, and also every even child starting at the fourth.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/QWjnm/1/).

It's not an ideal solution; you don't have any control over the `openingTimes` class any more, but I can't think of any solution where you do. Sorry!

Comment: "every other child starting at the fourth." is wrong, it's every other **even** child starting at the fourth.

Comment: @Apolo Hey, "every other" does not mean the same as "every". Look it up. And I'm not even sure the sentence is grammatically correct after your edit.

Comment: I just wanted to precise, but english is not my favorite language, re-edit if you think it's wrong

Comment: but "every other child starting at the fourth" make me think it's 4,5, 6 and so on...

Comment: @Apolo But it really means 4, 6, 8 and so on. I can edit so that it is both correct and clear though...